# Django testing - test if logged in user is owner of userdetails

Tags: django, unit-testing

So I've made this little app where users have an account page were they can see and update their own details.

Now I'm writing some tests for the DetailView and UpdateView. I would like to verify that the logged in user is indeed the owner of the user details.

I've created a testdatabase with different users and added three tests.

- Check if the user is logged in
- When a user is logged in does he get the right template
- When a user is logged in does he see his own details only

The problem is in the last test, I tried to retrieve the logged in user and compare this with the current user details but this isn't working. Any ideas?

Edit: The test now passes successfully, so the user data belongs to the user who is logged in.

However this doesn't feel like a valid test method. Even though the user matches the owner of the details I'm looking for a way to verify if a user would be able to access the details of someone else.

Before, I would use the user id in the url like;

## urls.py

```
path('account/<int:pk>/', views.AccountDetailView.as_view(), name='account_detail'),
```

So someone would be able to edit the urlpath and access someone else his details if the LoginRequiredMixin wasn't added.

By using get_object(self):, this is no longer possible, what's the best way to test this possibility?

## views.py

```
class AccountDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'account.html'

    '''
    Retrieve user id from "self.request.user" instead of retrieving the user_id
    from the URL. This way we can eliminate the user id in the URL.
    '''
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

## test_views.py

```
class LoggedInTestCase(TestCase):
    '''
    Setup LoginInTestCase 
    '''
    def setUp(self):
        guest = User.objects.create_user(username='john.doe', email='john@doe.com', password='1234')
        guest_other = User.objects.create_user(username='david.doe', email='david@doe.com', password='5678')


class AccountDetailViewTests(LoggedInTestCase):
    '''
    Test the UserDetailView which shows the user details
    '''
    def test_login_required_redirection(self):
        '''
        Test if only logged in users can view the user detail page
        '''
        self.url = reverse('account_detail')
        login_url = reverse('account_login')
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '{login_url}?next={url}'.format(login_url=login_url, url=self.url))

    def test_logged_in_uses_correct_template(self):
        '''
        Test if logged in user gets to see the correct template
        '''
        login = self.client.login(username='john.doe', password='1234')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('account_detail'))
        # Check if our guest is logged in
        self.assertEqual(str(response.context['user']), 'john.doe')
        # Check for response "succes"
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # Check if we get the correct template
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'account.html')

    def test_accountdetails_belong_to_logged_in_user(self):
        '''
        Test if logged in user can only see the details that belong to him
        '''
        login = self.client.login(username='john.doe', password='1234')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('account_detail'))
        # Check if our guest is logged in matches the
        user = User.objects.get(username='john.doe') #edited
        self.assertEqual(response.context['user'], user)
        # Check for response "success"
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: What is output of `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on get_queryset, at first I used the user.id from the url. I guess the queryset is still a leftover, I'll edit the question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`client.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) method returns `True` if the login succeeded, it does not return the user.

You can fetch the user from the database.

```
user = User.objects.get(username='john.doe')
self.assertEqual(response.context['user'], user)
```

Or compare the string as in your other test.

```
self.assertEqual(str(response.context['user']), 'john.doe')
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, I've used the first option since it would allow me to write a second test and change the user. Even though this answers my question it does not feel like a valid method for testing user details access.

Comment: What doesn't feel valid about this method? If you still used `'account/<int:pk>/'`, I would add a test fetches `/account/<pk_of_other_user/` and checks that it returns 404 or another suitable response. For your current `get_object` approach, you could add a test that does `self.assertNotEqual(response.context['user'], other_user)`, but it doesn't seem particularly useful to me, since you have already checked `self.assertEqual(response.context['user'], user)`.

Comment: Dear Alasdair, thanks for your comment. I indeed added a test to check if the current user would not be 'other_user' but this wouldn't make any sense. With the get_object approach their is no need to send a 404 response anymore since a user can not modify the url. Thank you.